# Uploading File (IfromFile) via HttpClient To webApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Need help. I am trying to save or uploud a file (IFormFile) from a Project Web to the Web Api, consuming the web api via httpClient. I am getting the following error: System.NotSupportedException: The collection type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary' on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile.Headers' is not supported.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haBQG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Wyt.png)

Comment: Try to add `[JsonIgnore]` to your `IFormFile` attribute

Comment: Hi @FortunatoCassule, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NotSupportedException: The collection type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary' on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile.Headers' is not supported.

It seems that you are serializing a `FormFile`, which cause the above issue.

> I am trying to save or uploud a file (IFormFile) from a Project Web to the Web Api, consuming the web api via httpClient.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Online([FromForm]CandidaturaAddModel model)
{

    var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    formContent.Add(new StringContent(model.Senha), "Senha");
    formContent.Add(new StringContent(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(model.AnoLectvo)), "AnoLectvo");

    //...
    //for other properties, such as Email, Genero etc
    //...

    formContent.Add(new StreamContent(model.Foto.OpenReadStream()), "Foto", Path.GetFileName(model.Foto.FileName));

    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:xxxx/");

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("/api/xxx/CandidaturaAdd", formContent);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //....
    }
```

Test Result

[image]